# Edit image file in S3 bucket using AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Some images which is already uploaded on AWS S3 bucket and of course there is a lot of image. I want to edit and replace those images and I want to do it on AWS server, Here I want to use aws lambda.

I already can do my job from my local pc. But it takes a very long time. So I want to do it on server.

Is it possible?

Comment: Do you want to do it on an Amazon EC2 instance (server), or do you want to do it using AWS Lambda? You mention both in your question.

Comment: I want to use lambda, if it is not possible on lambda then i will try in EC2

Comment: Traditionally, an AWS Lambda function is **triggered** when a file is uploaded to S3. This would tell the Lambda function which image file to process. You mention that your images are **already uploaded**, so how should the Lambda function know which files it should process?

Comment: Thanks. that is what i exactly want to know. I am not going to use lambda.

Comment: You _could_ use Lambda for the task, but you would need a way of passing which files to process. If you have an existing backlog, it is probably easier to run your code on Amazon EC2. Then, if you wish to automatically process images in future, use a Lambda function.

Comment: Yes, now i will do this. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately directly editing file in S3 is not supported [Check out the thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=46710). To overcome the situation, you need to download the file locally in server/local machine, then edit it and re-upload it again to s3 bucket. Also you can enable versions

- For node js you can use [Jimp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp)
- For java: [ImageIO](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html)
- For python: [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

or you can use any technology to edit it and later upload it using aws-sdk.

For lambda function you can use [serverless framework](https://serverless.com/) - https://serverless.com/
I have made youtube videos long back. This is related to how get started with aws-lambda and serverless

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uXZCNnzSMkI

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger a Lambda using the AWS SDK.
Write a Lambda to process a single image and deploy it.

Then locally use the AWS SDK to list the images in the bucket and invoke the Lambda (asynchronously) for each file using `invoke`. I would also save somewhere which files have been processed so you can continue if something fails.

Note that the default limit for Lambda is 1000 concurrent executions, so to avoid reaching the limit you can send messages to an SQS queue (which then triggers the Lambda) or just retry when `invoke` throws an error.